# client_side_validation install giving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am following the instructions on client_side_validations install as described here https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations. After adding to the Gemfile and running the bundle command I run the command "rails g client_side_validations:install" as described in the documentation. This is expected to install two files

config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb
public/javascripts/rails.validations.js

However, when I run the command, the client_side_validatins.rb is created but I get an error regarding rails.validations.js as below

```
  create  config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb
Could not find "../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/rails.validations.js" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are:
C:/temp/testrails/delme2/lib/templates/client_side_validations/install
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/client_side_validations-3.0.7/lib/generators/templates
```

The install command is looking for the file and can't find it. Where does the rails.validations.js come from? I tried it with a clean project to be sure and get the same result and can't seem to find anything related in my search.

The client_side_validations gem I have through bundler is 3.0.7 and I am on Ruby 1.9.2p180 Rails 3.0.5.

Thanks,
-S

Answer (score 2):

You should first install jquery-rails, run install methods of it and then try to go ahead with client-side-validations.
Let us know what happens this way.

Comment: Also helps to install it with `--ui`to install JQuery-UI.

Comment: I actually did install jquery-rails using "rails generate jquery:install --ui" before trying to install client_side_validations gem. The jquery-rails gems installed without any issues. After that when I run the command to install the client_side_validations gem I keep getting this error which is coming from install_generator.rb ---- ./lib/generators/client_side_validations/install_generator.rb:        copy_file
'../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/rails.validations.js', 'public/javascripts/r
ails.validations.js'

Comment: I have edited the original message to format it correctly so the error output shows better. Is there any other error output I should be looking at?

Comment: I guess, windows is having some probs detecting your gem paths properly. For now, you can copy paste rails.validations.js file from github.com to your public/javascripts folder. This should work fine.

Comment: Thanks rtdp. I see that the gem install didn't create the vendor directory under the client_side_validations gem and thus didn't copy the rails.validations.js file under vendor/assets/javascripts directory as the install script is expecting. I created the directory structure manually and copied the rails.validations.js file manually and the install command for client_side_validations now works fine. Looks like a bug in the way the gem is installed. I have opened an issue on github for this gem. Thanks!

Comment: This was confirmed to be a bug in 3.0.7 version of client_side_validations gem. Fix has been made in 3.0.8 and pushed out by the author today.